# Is the closed-form of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-k}}{k^2}$ known?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

I'm looking for an expression that yields the above sum.

It's a straight and simple question, feel free to move this post to any other section, if it's not in the appropriate section, I know this site can be pretty strict with questions:

Is $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-k}}{k^2}$ known?

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
Li_2( \frac{1}{e}).
\end{eqnarray*}
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function

Comment: Try evaluating $\sum{x^k\over k^2}$ ay $x={1\over e}$

Comment: If you don't like dilogarithms, follow saulspatz advice and use differentation of power series theorem

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Li_2(1%2Fe)) does not produce something helpful therefore I have doubts that a closed-form is known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making the problem more general
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-k x}}{k^n}=\text{Li}_n\left(e^{-x}\right)$$where appears the [polylogarithm function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) which is a special function.